# Pseudo-asymmetry-like situation in alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

We have pseudo-asymmetric carbons in optical isomerism which dictates that if 2 groups on the carbon atom are different in terms in configuration then the carbon is chiral. In alkenes can the same thing happen with respect to geometrical isomerism? For example consider [image]

If both the alkenes on the left were E or both Z, then certainly there wouldn't be any chance of geometrical isomerism. But as in this case if the configurations are different ,i.e, E and Z, can the alkene be contended for geometrical isomerism ,i.e., whether the compound is a Z or E isomer in terms of the middle alkene (to which a methyl group is attached)?

While giving the answer to this question, it would be extremely helpful if you cite the source of your information for me to look it up.

Comment: Related: [How to determine priorities for this compound according to the Cahn-Ingold-Prelog rules?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/31783/7951)

Comment: @Loong: It's not a question of finding the priorities but rather would even one be applicable in this case.

Comment: The second answer to that question answers your question exactly though. If one is E and one is Z, the Z substituent would have higher priority.