# Is a carbon chiral it two of its groups are cis - trans isomers?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality, cis-trans-isomerism

For example:

In this image, the two groups sticking to a carbon are cis-trans isomers. So does that make the carbon chiral, exhibiting optical properties?

What if the two groups were both having the same configuration(both cis or both trans), would it then be achiral?
[image: Chiral or not?]
Thanks for any help :D

Comment: Related: [Which alkene has a higher Cahn-Ingold-Prelog priority in (2Z,5E)-hepta-2,5-dien-4-ol?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/35099/7951)

Comment: So it'll exhibit optical properties and will have enantiomers? Thanks.

Comment: The other posters replied to your main question. I will add a couple of observations. 1) chirality is a property of the whole molecule, not of any of its parts in isolation; thus there are no 'chiral centers' or 'chiral' carbon atoms, there are _stereocenters_ and _stereogenic_ carbon atoms, which may be found in chiral _molecules_ . 2) having stereoisomers, or enantiomers in this case, is not the same as, or automatically implying, displaying optical properties; it is _likely_ to observe distinct optical properties in opposite enantiomers of the same molecule, but not a universal rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time all four groups bonded to carbon are distinct, including any sort of isomeric groups, you have a chiral center.  Comments associated with the related question referenced by @Loong (since deleted, unfortunately) indicate that the *cis* vs *trans* scenario is even included in the $R$ vs. $S$ naming convention.  This case is an $S$ configuration as the *cis* group takes second place and is counterclockwise from the hydroxyl group in the appropriate view.