# Why does 1-ethylidene-2,3-dimethylcyclopropane exhibit cis-trans isomerism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

I think the carbons 2 and 3 have different configuration according to the CIP rules which makes the groups different:

[image: 1-ethylidene-2,3-dimethylcyclopropane]

Am I correct? Is there any official criteria regarding these cases ?

Comment: This example should answer your question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134700/can-geometrical-isomers-be-enantiomers/134722#134722. Cis/trans doesn't mean much here.

Comment: [This](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58630/why-is-1-ethylidene-4-methylcyclohexane-chiral/96265#96265) is a related question and have accepted answer.